# Call method from an outside class using CodeDom

Tags: c#, class, methods, codedom

I have two methods; one of which resides outside of a class, the other inside a class. I would like to be able to use CodeDom to make a call from the method outside of the class, to the one inside of the class. This will be much easier to explain through the use of code...

**Class with method inside:**

```
public static class Public
{
    public static byte[] ReadAllData(string sFilePath)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[sFilePath.Length];
        b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sFilePath);
        return b;
    }  
}
```

** from another class:

```
Public.ReadAllData(@"C:\File.exe");
```

**I want to recreate the above using** `CodeDom` -

```
CodeMemberMethod method = new CodeMemberMethod();

method.Statements.Add(new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
new CodeVariableExpression("Public"), "ReadAllData"));
```

**The above code will produce the following output - but notice I was not able to pass any parameters!**

```
Public.ReadAllData;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use CodeDom to do this?  What is it you're trying to solve?

Comment: The entire purpose of my project is to be using CodeDom ...

Comment: Why do people always trying to harm themself so much..?:)

Comment: @Tigran, there are cases where dynamically generating code is useful. And I think using Reflection.Emit is much more painful than CodeDom and Expressions cannot be used for everything and are lacking important features in .Net 3.5.

Comment: @tigran The struggles I have with programming are what make it so intruiging to me! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

var invocation = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Public)),
    "ReadAllData", new CodePrimitiveExpression(@"C:\File.exe"));

var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
compiler.GenerateCodeFromExpression(invocation, stringWriter, null);
Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
```

This code produces the result

```
ConsoleApplication1.Public.ReadAllData("C:\\File.exe")
```

Another option is

```
var invocation = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(
        new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Public)),"ReadAllData"),
    new CodePrimitiveExpression(@"C:\File.exe"));
```

Using `CodeMethodReferenceExpression` this way could be useful when calling generic methods: you can specify type parameters in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used CodeDom a bit, but I think you'll want the [CodeMethodInvokeExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codemethodinvokeexpression.aspx), instead of CodePropertyReferenceExpression.  It looks like CodePropertyReferenceExpression is generating a statement that is accessing a property value, rather than invoking a method.

There is a Parameters property on CodeMethodInvokeExpression that will allow you to specify the parameters to pass to the method you are wanting to invoke.

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem passing parameters to a method within a single class, but I can't figure out how to pass parameters to a method of another class. That is my main issue. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my CodeDom brain has too many cobwebs to be able to recall how exactly that works.  I've been using ExpressionTrees for this sort of work since 3.5, so I've lost all of my former CodeDom foo